# jQuery - Custom Gallery - Works in FF, Chrome, Safari & IE8, but not IE7 - pointers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-7

I'm really baffled with the following.

When the gallery is created in FF/Chrome etc, clicking next moves the image on one and the hover state remains for you to click again.  In IE7, the image moves on one, then the hover state fails, and doesn't reappear.  Other effects I have on my page continue to function.

My jQuery may not be the best, so I apologise for the mess.  Other than the problem at hand, any general jQuery pointers welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm11-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />

    <title>GA - 2009 yee haw</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dimensions.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @import "/css/screen.css";
    </style>
</head>


<body>





            <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--//
                function DrawGalleryOptions(div) {

                    $('gallery').css({width: '503px'});
                    $(div).append('<div class="gallery-title"><p style="font-size:14px;">no title</p><div class="gallery-bg gallery-bg-small"></div></div>');
                    $(div).append('<div class="gallery-nav"></div>');
                    $('.gallery-nav').append('<div class="gallery-bg"></div><div class="gallery-controls"><p class="gall-title"><a class="gallleft" href="#galleryleft" title="">Previous Image</a><a class="gallright" href="#galleryright" title="">Next Image</a></p></div>');

                    $('.gallery-title, .gallery-nav, .gallery-bg').css({ position: 'absolute', left: '0px', height: '30px', width: '503px' });
                    $('.gallery-nav').css({ height: '60px', bottom: '-60px' });
                    $('.gallery-bg').css({ backgroundColor: '#5974c5', opacity: 0.7, height: '60px', zIndex: 1000 });
                    $('.gallery-title').css({ top: '-30px'});
                    $('.gallery-controls').css({ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1002 });
                    $('.gallery-bg-small').css({height: '30px'});
                    $('.gallery-title p').css({zIndex: 1002, color: '#ffffff', position: 'absolute', padding: '5px'});
                    $('.gallery-controls p').css({ posistion: 'absolute', zIndex: 1005, left: '0px', top: '0px' });
                    $('a.gallleft').css({ width: '82px', height: '45px', display: 'block', textIndent: '0', backgroundImage: 'url(/image/galleryleft.gif)', backgroundPosition: 'left top', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', fontSize: '11px', color: '#ffffff', top: '15px', left: '15px', position: 'absolute', paddingTop: '25px' });
                    $('a.gallright').css({ width: '53px', height: '45px', display: 'block', textIndent: '0', backgroundImage: 'url(/image/galleryright.gif)', backgroundPosition: 'right top', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', fontSize: '11px', color: '#ffffff', top: '15px', left: '430px', position: 'absolute', paddingTop: '25px' });
                }

                function ShowGalleryOptions() {

                    jQuery.easing.def = "easeOutQuint";
                    $('.gallery-title').animate({ top: '0px' }, 800);
                    $('.gallery-nav').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 800);

                }

                function HideGalleryOptions() {

                    $('.gallery-title').animate({ top: '-30px' }, 800);
                    $('.gallery-nav').animate({ bottom: '-60px' }, 800);

                }

                function StopAll() {

                    $('.gallery-title').stop();
                    $('.gallery-nav').stop();

                }


                function MoveGallery(pic) {

                    $('#test2').html('>> <br />' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].src + " " + pic[_GalleryCurrent].height + " " + pic[_GalleryCurrent].width + "<br />Current: " + _GalleryCurrent);

                    $('.gallery').append('<img id="gallery-current" style="display:none;" src="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].src + '" width="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].width + '" height="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].height + '" alt="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].alt + '" />');
                    $('#gallery-current').css({ opacity: 0, display: 'block' });
                    $('.gallery img').css({ position: 'absolute', top: '0px', left: '0px' });
                    //jQuery.easing.def = "easeOutElastic";

                    $('.gallery-title p').html(pic[_GalleryCurrent].alt);

                    $('#gallery-current').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1200, function() {

                        $('#gallery-last').remove();
                        $('#gallery-current').attr('id', 'gallery-last');

                    });

                }


                $(function() {

                    var pic;
                    pic = $(".gallery").children("img");
                    _GalleryMax = pic.length - 1;
                    _GalleryCurrent = 0;

                    //$('#test2').html('>><br />' + pic[_].src + " " + pic[0].height + " " + pic[0].width + "<br />Current: " + _GalleryCurrent);

                    $('.gallery').css({ height: 283, overflow: 'hidden', position: 'relative' });
                    $('.gallery').html('');

                    DrawGalleryOptions('.gallery');

                    $('.gallery').append('<img id="gallery-last" src="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].src + '" width="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].width + '" height="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].height + '" alt="' + pic[_GalleryCurrent].alt + '" />');
                    $('.gallery-title p').html(pic[_GalleryCurrent].alt);

                    $('.gallery').hover(function() {

                        //alert('on');
                        StopAll();
                        ShowGalleryOptions();

                    },
                    function() {

                        //alert('off');
                        StopAll();
                        HideGalleryOptions();

                    });

                    $('a.gallright').click(function() {

                        $('#gallery-current').stop(false, true);

                        //alert('boota');
                        _GalleryCurrent = _GalleryCurrent + 1;
                        if (_GalleryCurrent > _GalleryMax) {
                            _GalleryCurrent = 0;
                        }

                        MoveGallery(pic);

                    });

                    $('a.gallleft').click(function() {

                        $('#gallery-current').stop(false, true);

                        //alert('boota');
                        _GalleryCurrent = _GalleryCurrent - 1;
                        if (_GalleryCurrent < 0) {
                            _GalleryCurrent = _GalleryMax;
                        }

                        MoveGallery(pic);

                    });

                });

                //-->

            </script>

            <div class="gallery">

                <img class="gall-img" src="/image/gallery1.jpg" width="503" height="283" alt="Person on a lake" />
                <img class="gall-img" src="/image/gallery2.jpg" width="503" height="283" alt="Building university" />
                <img class="gall-img" src="/image/gallery3.jpg" width="503" height="283" alt="Random colours" />
                <img class="gall-img" src="/image/gallery4.jpg" width="503" height="283" alt="Abstract - dark blue?" />
                <img class="gall-img" src="/image/gallery5.jpg" width="503" height="283" alt="Random abstract" />

            </div>

            <div id="test2" style="font-size:18px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

any help greatly appreciated!!

EDIT #1:
Further to the above, I'd read that IE7 has issues with the img selector, but I've tried changing this to a generic classname etc to no avail.  Any more clues?

EDIT #2:
I'm still struggling with this - I've added a live example here:  (too new to add links it seems, sorry!)

Comment: http://gallery.andycopley.co.uk/gallery.htm

Comment: Ooh!  A bit of progress.  I've amended the example so the gallery is too high.  using this example, you can see in IE7 that the gallery controls still appear but BENEATH the images.  So Keith was right with the CSS suggestion. 

I still can't seem to fix this however, no amount of zIndex trickery seems to force the images back beneath the gallery controls.

Please tell me there's a simple/elegant css solution!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue after much playing. As Keith suggested it was simply a CSS bug.

IE7 needed a little reminding what zindex levels some of the elements were on, so I inserted the following

```
$('.gallery-nav, .gallery-title').css({ position: 'absolute', left: '0px', zIndex: '1100' }); // random reassignement of gallery zIndex, because IE7 doesn't behave
```

Inside the move gallery function (just before the animation).

Joy!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting a test page on a publicly accessible server for others to see live in our own environments with IE7.

It would allow us to see much more quickly what's going on and help understand and diagnose the behavior.

I could c&p your code, but I'd still have to find pics, etc. to even examine it.

Until then, check out Firebug Lite for IE: http://getfirebug.com/lite.html and just include the following:

```
<script src="http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js"></script>
```

I'm guessing off the top of my head that b/c it works in the other browsers and you're using jQuery which is very well normalized that it's probably a CSS issue, but until I see a sample page, it's just a quick guess.

Comment: The Firebug lite pointer is what finally gave it to me - so many thanks.  I'd vote you up one if I had the power!

Comment: Glad to help. I know that you'll vote me up when you get the rep. ;) Thanks.